# SQLite: how to search multiple columns without returning duplicate rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, search, sqlite

trying to solve this with my limited knowledge of SQL and I'm stuck. :)

This is being done in **SQLite 3** and **Python 3**.

I've 'JOIN'ed 2 tables (**names** and **data**).

I'm trying to search 2 columns in the result for user supplied text (case insensitive). If a match is found in either column, then return the row.

The problem I have, is that if the text is found in the name columns, I get multiple rows returned (I guess because there are multiple rows with the name name).

The required data is the '**name_id**'

Here's a mockup of the join (there are other columns I haven't included here):

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    |  name_id    |     name       |      data_id     |    data       |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   100       |   John Smith   |        200       |  grey hair    |
    |   100       |   John Smith   |        201       |  hairy teeth  |
    |   101       |  Jerry Jones   |        202       |  white teeth  |
    |   103       | Barry Johnson  |        256       |  brown hair   |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, if I search for "teeth", I get:

```
    |   100       |   John Smith   |        201       |  hairy teeth  |
    |   101       |  Jerry Jones   |        202       |  white teeth  |
```

and, if I search for "hair", I get:

```
    |   100       |   John Smith   |        200       |  grey hair    |
    |   100       |   John Smith   |        201       |  hairy teeth  |
    |   103       | Barry Johnson  |        256       |  brown hair   |
```

or, if I search for "john", I get:

```
    |   100       |   John Smith   |        200       |  grey hair    |
    |   100       |   John Smith   |        201       |  hairy teeth  |
    |   103       | Barry Johnson  |        256       |  brown hair   |
```

But what I actually want is only one row returned based on each '**name_id**' so:

```
    |   100       |   John Smith   |        200       |  grey hair    |
    |   103       | Barry Johnson  |        256       |  brown hair   |
```

The remaining SQLite command looks like this:

```
WHERE data LIKE "%john%" OR name LIKE "%john%" COLLATE NOCASE
```

I've tried using 'DISTINCT' but it appears to remove duplicate rows based upon the specified column. These missing rows contain data that is then not searched.

Thanks.

Comment: And what did you expected to happen in such cases? How should your app behave when multiple rows are meeting your criteria?

Comment: If you simply want the first row for each `name_id` you could use `GROUP BY name_id` But I believe the order in which the results are returned is determined by the order of the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I'm assuming you simply want the first record for each unique value in the `name_id` column. If that is the case then your query should look like this.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  names n
  JOIN data d ON d.name_id = n.name_id
WHERE
  LCASE(n.name) LIKE '%john%' // Force lower so only 1 WHERE statement
GROUP BY
  n.name_id
```

`GROUP BY` should 'collapse' all the data on whatever column you select. So lets say you wanted to count the amount of results for each `name_id` you could change your `SELECT` statement as follows.

```
SELECT
  n.name_id,
  COUNT(n.name_id) AS result_count
FROM
// Rest of query
```

If you don't use an aggregate function like `SUM, COUNT, etc` then it simply drops all but the first result.

If this isn't what you are looking for LMK. Hope that helps.

Comment: yeah I know I was simply stating that is how the `SELECT` portion should look like. Updated w/ comment for clarity.

Comment: Thanks Adam. `GROUP BY` was the magic phrase I needed here. I've added that to my query and it's now working correctly. :)

Comment: No problem anytime.

Comment: @teracow For reference - you could also use a correlated subquery, eg: `select name_id from names where name like '%john%' or exists (select * from data where data like '%hairy%' and names.name_id = name_id)` which will give you 100 and 103.

Comment: @JonClements - wow, this SQL thing is pretty amazing ... I've lots to learn. :)

Answer (score 0):

With the same assumptions as the previous answer (i.e. you're looking for the first record for the unique name), I'd suggest the following:

```
select    names.name_id
          , <names_fields>
          , group_concat(data,';')
from      names
          join  (select name_id, data from data_table)
            on names.name_id = data.name_id
where     name_id
group by  <name_fields>
```

More on group_concat [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html).